# Passing arguments in a factory pattern

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

I am learning Domain Driven Design and I am in the ['naively confident'](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jD3WLZ1MLLc/UWGCLCPS5vI/AAAAAAAAAC8/YIyzwJRRJEg/s1600/Learning-Curve-1024x709.png) phase right now. DDD(the blue book) speaks about having a factory pattern for building aggregates. I tried using it for my application and in one of the scenarios it just doesn't seem right and I dont know how to proceed. Below is my case:

```
class CompanyFactory {
    public Company getCompany(Type type, Long numOfShares) {
        switch(type) {
            case PUBLIC:
                return new PublicCompany(numOfShares);
            case PRIVATE:
                return new PrivateCompany();
        }
}
```

Now the argument `'numOfShares'` is relevant only for the `PublicCompany`. But when my type is `'PRIVATE'`, I still have to send the `'numOfShares'` even though it wont be used.

I tried AbstractFactory but in that case each factory would create exactly one type of object and IMHO it misses the whole point of using a factory in the first place. Any pointers on how to do this will be great.

Comment: Private companies are usually significantly different from public companies in many aspects so there is not really a good idea to use one class to represent both of them. You risk ending up with lots of if-thens all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A factory is mostly useful to abstract away a complex creation process or to decouple the client code from concrete implementations where it makes sense.

Here I suppose that you may have implemented a generic `createCompany(String type, Map<String, String> info)` application service method that is called from the presentation layer and so you must instantiate the right concrete company based on the type dynamically.

While I agree that this use case would benefit from a factory, perhaps you could make the process more straight forward by defining explicit `createPublicCompany` and `createPrivateCompany` methods on the application service, leaving it to the presentation layer to call the right one. You would therefore push the decision making upwards, where it has to be made anyway in the first place (e.g. to show the right fields) and you wouldn't need a factory anymore.

If that isin't practical for some reasons and you still need to dynamically choose the concrete implementation from a `Type` then your factory contract will have to be abstract enough to accomodate all company types.

If you implemented a generic `createCompany` method at the application level then you already solved that problem before.

Comment: Not really sure what this all have to do with "presentation layer" to be honest.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev It's the approach I chose to demonstrate the problem, but I could have done so by only focusing on the domain. The presentation layer is usually the direct client of application services, among other potential clients. I just wanted to emphasis that when you let the client better describe its intention then everything becomes much easier. I could have made my point by focusing on the fact that creating a public and private company are probably seen as completely different processes from a business point of view as well so they deserve different entry points.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using it for my application and in one of the scenarios it just doesn't seem right and I dont know how to proceed

I think part of the problem is the model you have; for example, a private company can have shares, the difference is that they are traded internally, and not publicly.

- So for example you could solve the problem by adjusting the model such that `numOfShares` is not a primitive but a proper VO, representing the number of Public and Private shares, and consumed by the concrete's constructor appropriately.
- You could take the approach that since the number of shares a company has to trade can change, the setting of the shares doesn't need to be an invariant operation, and can be a separate method (and if in your case, you don't care about privately held company shares, such a method might only exist on a concrete PublicCompany implementation)
- Or, you could re-think the model and view the Shares as a first-class concept (i.e. a proper Aggregate root) whereby they are not just a sub-property of a company but exist in their own right, with references to the entities that hold them (public or private)

In the end, it is going to depend on how you model your Domain, which in turn depends on the problem you are trying to solve; and in most cases, when you run into a situation where you can't quite seem to satisfy your requirements with a single Factory, it's a good sign that you are dealing with separate Domain concepts and either need to re-think the model or use more than one factory.